# How to get Month wise data from SQL using PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(CreateDate) [Year], MONTH(CreateDate) [Month], DATENAME(MONTH,CreateDate) [Month Name],COUNT(id) [Total], 
    CASE 
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  1 THEN 'Pending'
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  2 THEN 'Commited'
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  3 THEN 'Confirmed'
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  4 THEN 'Canceled'
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  5 THEN 'Failed'
            ELSE ''
        END AS  PaymentStatus,count(ID) as counts 
    FROM [dbo].[BankPaymentRequest]
    GROUP BY YEAR(CreateDate), MONTH(CreateDate), DATENAME(MONTH, CreateDate), PaymentStatus) as asd
    PIVOT( SUM(counts) 
    FOR PaymentStatus IN ([Pending],[Commited],[Confirmed],[Canceled],[Failed])) AS MNamePivot
```

I want Year-Month wise data from this query with respective [Pending],[Commited],[Confirmed],[Canceled],[Failed] transaction count. Basically i want Month wise Transaction count for Pending,Commited,Confirmed,Canceled and Failed.

I am using Sql Server 2016
Now i am getting exact data but Months are listed twice or thrice.

I want data like below format

```
Year Month Total Pending Commited   Confirmed   Canceled Failed
2016  Jan  34      1        4            63          840      157
2016  Feb  34      8        4            62          8        15
2016  Mar  65      1        4            63          840      157
2016  Dec  56      8        4            62          8        15
2017  Jan  78      1        4            63          840      157
2017  Feb  89      8        4            62          8        15
2017  Mar  67      1        4            63          840      157
2017  Dec   8      4        62           8           15       345
```

Please help me for such query or any alternative query.

Comment: First you need to decide which DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server. Then you need to provide some details so others can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If you are sure about sql server 2008 then remove mysql

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting your existing query inside of a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) and then `GROUP BY` the year and month while summing the numbers.

```
WITH preselect AS 
(
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(CreateDate) [Year], MONTH(CreateDate) [Month], DATENAME(MONTH,CreateDate) [Month Name],COUNT(id) [Total], 
    CASE 
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  1 THEN 'Pending'
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  2 THEN 'Commited'
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  3 THEN 'Confirmed'
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  4 THEN 'Canceled'
            WHEN PaymentStatus =  5 THEN 'Failed'
            ELSE ''
        END AS  PaymentStatus,count(ID) as counts 
    FROM [dbo].[BankPaymentRequest]
    GROUP BY YEAR(CreateDate), MONTH(CreateDate), DATENAME(MONTH, CreateDate), PaymentStatus) as asd
    PIVOT( SUM(counts) 
    FOR PaymentStatus IN ([Pending],[Commited],[Confirmed],[Canceled],[Failed])) AS MNamePivot
)

SELECT [YEAR],[MONTH],SUM(TOTAL)'TOTAL',SUM(Pending)'Pending'
                    ,SUM(Commited)'Commited',SUM(Confirmed)'Confirmed'
                    ,SUM(Canceled)'Canceled',SUM(Failed)'Failed'
FROM preselect
GROUP BY [YEAR],[MONTH]
```

Comment: Yes Bro Its working for me perfectly. Its give me perfect result.Thank you.

Comment: @PramodLawate, you are welcome. Please mark it as the accepted answer if it is what you needed.